# How to detect a CD, from the command line in FreeBSD8

Tags: freebsd

I would like to be able to tell if the CD drawer is closed, with a disc present, on FreeBSD 8.

Back in FreeBSD6, I could use `cdcontrol status volume` which would return "No volume level info available" until there was a disk present.

In FreeBSD 8, it returns "Left volume = 255, right volume = 255" no matter if a disc is there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have a knack for figuring out my problem, just after posting here on SU.

In this case, it turns out that cdcontrol needs the /dev/cd0 (ATAPI interface) to provide that little status message "No volume level info available".

A simple `kldload atapicam` and it was working as I remember it. (and added to my loader.conf, of course)